# Mapping results from API

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, es6-promise

I am trying to make a list of images for each movie, which I have found calling fetch API's to themoviedb.

I am using fetch to get the images, and the console.log prints all fine.

```
getImages(movieId).then((imgs) => {
        setImages(imgs.backdrops);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Now when map the arrays I am getting "Undefined".

```
{
  images.map((img) => {
     <Image
         source={img.file_path ? { uri: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${img.file_path}` } :     null}
         style={styles.movieImages}
     />;
  })
}
```

Weird thing is when I test out if the API works by just showing the first images, it works.
So it works when I do this.

```
<Image
       source={images[0].file_path ? 
{ uri: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${images[0].file_path}` } : null}
        style={styles.movieImages}
/>
```

it seems I am not mapping correctly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your map function did not return anything. Please add `return` before your `<Image />`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  images.map((img) => {
    return (
      <Image
        source={img.file_path ? { uri: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${img.file_path}` } :     null}
        style={styles.movieImages}
     />;
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: While this might work, there needs to be some explanation or commentary.

Comment: your "map" function do not return anything